# C# RichTextBox edit count character deleted

Tags: c#, richtextbox, textchanged

I have a RichTextBox in a C# project. Adding characters and counting the number of characters per line works.
The issue comes when I try to delete characters with the Backspace Key
I have commented out the code I have tried while pressing the Backspace Key
I also tried to use a KeyPress event to manage counting characters deleted complete fail.
If anyone would like to test the code here are the properties of the RichTextBox **Name rtbInfo**.
**Size 347 by 120 Font 10.8 Bold WordWrap False NO Scroll Bars Max Length 135**

**GOAL Increase the variable res by 1 for each character or space deleted with the press of the Backspace Key.**

I would prefer to not use KeyPress KeyUp or KeyDown Events if at all possible.
Happy to consider code suggestions with those Event designs.

```
public partial class frmRTB : Form
{
    int Count = 0;
    int Lines = 0;
    int cT = 0;
    int res = 0;
   
    public frmRTB()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //rtbInfo.KeyPress += rtbInfo_KeyPress;
      /*=== This Must be here to register rtbInfo ===*/
      /*=============================================*/
    }

    private void frmRTB_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ActiveControl = rtbInfo;
    }

    /*private void rtbInfo_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        
        if (rtbInfo.TextLength == 0)
        {
            tbMessage.Text = "Nothing to Delete";
            return;
        }
       
        if (e.KeyChar == ((char)Keys.Back) & (char.IsControl('\b')))
        {
         
            //rtbInfo.Text = rtbInfo.Text.Remove(rtbInfo.TextLength - 1, 0);
            //rtbInfo.Select(rtbInfo.TextLength - 0, 0);
            //rtbInfo.ScrollToCaret();
            //cT = cT - 1;
            //res = - 1;// Last edit was res - cT ?
            //tbCount.Text = "Back Fire";
            //e.Handled = true;
        }
    }*/
  
    public void rtbInfo_TextChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Count = rtbInfo.TextLength;
        Lines = rtbInfo.Lines.Length;

        foreach (char chr in rtbInfo.Text)
        {
            if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(chr))
            {
                cT = cT + 1;
                res = 33 - cT;
            }

            /*
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[\b]+$");
            //Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[\b\S\t\D\W]+$");

            if (regex.IsMatch(rtbInfo.Text))
            {
              tbCount.Text = "Use BACKSPACE Key to Edit";
            }*/
   

        //if (chr == '\b')
        //if (chr == ((char)Keys.Back))
        // tried above if statments they do not fire

        // This fires when any key is entered NOT just the Backspace key
      /*if (char.IsControl('\b'))// & !(char.IsLetterOrDigit(chr)))
        {
        //rtbInfo.Text = rtbInfo.Text.Remove(rtbInfo.TextLength - 1, 0);
        //rtbInfo.Select(rtbInfo.TextLength - 0, 0);
        //rtbInfo.ScrollToCaret();
         res = +1;
         tbCount.Text = "Use BACKSPACE Key to Edit";
       }*/

            if (Lines == 5 | Count == 135)
             {
                 rtbInfo.ReadOnly = true;
             }

              if (rtbInfo.ReadOnly == true)
              {
                  txtBoxMsg.Text = "";
                  tbMessage.Text = "";
                  tbCount.Text = "Use BACKSPACE Key to Edit";
              }

              if (rtbInfo.Text.EndsWith("\n"))
              {
                  cT = 0;
                  res = 0;
              }

              if (cT == 33)
              {
                   SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
                   rtbInfo.ScrollToCaret();
                   rtbInfo.Focus();
                   cT = 0;
                   res = 0; 
              }

              if (rtbInfo.ReadOnly == true)
              { 
                  string message = "Press YES to edit Notes" + '\n' + "        NO Clear Notes";
                  string title = "Edit Notes";
                  MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;
                  DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(message, title, buttons);
               if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
               {
                   rtbInfo.ReadOnly = false;
                   SendKeys.Send("{BACKSPACE}");
                   rtbInfo.ScrollToCaret();
                   rtbInfo.Focus();
                   cT = 0;
                   res = 0;
              }
              else
              {
                   rtbInfo.ReadOnly = false;
                   rtbInfo.Clear();
                   tbCount.Text = "All Notes Remove"; 
              }
              }

              if (res == 0)
              {
                  res = 33;
              }
                txtBoxMsg.Text = "Total of " + (135 - Count) + " can be entered & " + (5 - Lines) + " Lines";
                tbMessage.Text = "Total of " + res + " more char can be entered on line " + Lines;
                //tbCount.Text = "Count is " + Count + " cT " + cT + " res " + res;// For Testing
                return;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using both TextChanged & KeyPress events
While that solution worked I decided to put all the code in a KeyPress event ONLY.
One HUGE mistake in my original question was in InitializeComponent
Look up and read when & how to use this method. Enjoy the Code

```
   public partial class frmKPO : Form
{
    int rtbTotLen;
    int linesTot;
    int lineNum;
    int res1;
    int count1;
    int res2;
    int count2;
    int res3;
    int count3;
    int res4;
    int count4;
  
    public frmKPO()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void rtbInfo_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        rtbTotLen = rtbInfo.TextLength;
        linesTot = rtbInfo.Lines.Length;
        lineNum = (5 - linesTot);

        txtBoxMsg.Text = "Total of " + (135 - rtbTotLen) + " can be entered on " + (5 - lineNum) + " Lines";

        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back)
        {
            if (lineNum == 1)
            {
                --res1;
            }
            if (lineNum == 2)
            {
                --res2;
            }
            if (lineNum == 3)
            {
                --res3;
            }
            if (lineNum == 4)
            {
                --res4;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (lineNum == 1)
            {
                ++res1;
            }
            if (lineNum == 2)
            {
                ++res2;
            }
            if (lineNum == 3)
            {
                ++res3;
            }
            if (lineNum == 4)
            {
                ++res4;
            }
        }


        if (lineNum == 4)
        {
            count4 = 33 - res4;
            tbMessage.Text = "Total of " + count4 + " more char can be entered on line " + (5 - lineNum) + "";
            if (count4 == 0)
            {
                SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
                rtbInfo.ScrollToCaret();
                rtbInfo.Focus();
            }
        }
        else if (lineNum == 3)
        {
            count3 = 33 - res3;
            tbMessage.Text = "Total of " + count3 + " more char can be entered on line " + (5 - lineNum) + "";
            if (count3 == 0)
            {
                SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
                rtbInfo.ScrollToCaret();
                rtbInfo.Focus();
            }
        }
        else if (lineNum == 2)
        {
            count2 = 33 - res2;
            tbMessage.Text = "Total of " + count2 + " more char can be entered on line " + (5 - lineNum) + "";
            if (count2 == 0)
            {
                SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
                rtbInfo.ScrollToCaret();
                rtbInfo.Focus();
            }
        }
        else if (lineNum == 1)
        {
            count1 = 33 - res1;
            tbMessage.Text = "Total of " + count1 + " more char can be entered on line " + (5 - lineNum) + "";
            if (count1 == 0)
            {
                SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
                rtbInfo.ScrollToCaret();
                rtbInfo.Focus();
            }
        }
        if (linesTot == 5 | rtbTotLen == 135)
        {
            rtbInfo.ReadOnly = true;
        }

        if (rtbInfo.ReadOnly == true)
        {
            txtBoxMsg.Text = "";
            tbMessage.Text = "";
            tbCount.Text = "Use BACKSPACE Key to Edit";
        }

        if (rtbInfo.ReadOnly == true)
        {
            txtBoxMsg.Text = "";
            tbMessage.Text = "";
            tbCount.Text = "Use BACKSPACE Key to Edit";

            string message = "Press YES to edit Notes" + '\n' + "        NO Clear Notes";
            string title = "Edit Notes";
            MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(message, title, buttons);
            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                rtbInfo.ReadOnly = false;
                SendKeys.Send("{BACKSPACE}");
                rtbInfo.ScrollToCaret();
                rtbInfo.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                rtbInfo.ReadOnly = false;
                rtbInfo.Clear();
                tbCount.Text = "All Notes Remove";
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnToStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
        frmStart fS = new frmStart();
        fS.Show();
    }

    private void frmKPO_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ActiveControl = rtbInfo;
        tbMessage.Text = "Total of " + 33 + " more char can be entered on line " + 1 + "";
    }
}
```